# My android xml layout, stucks

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have this android layout that I've created, now I wanted to add a new button but I find out that I can't put it in the center ! I can only put it on the left or right sides ..

I've tried

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

but still the same !

and btw, I'm using a linear layout

Comment: try `android:gravity`

Answer (score 0):

Apply `android:layout_gravity="center"` onto your `LinearLayout` and not your `Button`. This should center it. If you just want to center it vertically or horizontally, set `layout_gravity` to `center_horizontal` or `center_vertical`.

Answer (score 0):

Try , this to ur LinearLayout. And tell us how it works.

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your button in a relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `RelativeLayout` and set you button, and add to button parameters by your need:

```
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 or/and
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 or just 
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```